# Oracle SQL Developer - ORA-01006

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am using SQL Developer version 3.2.20.10 on an Oracle 12c database.  While trying to type a simple query in a worksheet:

```
SELECT * FROM JTEMP_PARTIAL;
```

I get a pop-up with the "ORA-01006: Bind variable does not exist".  It seems to be triggering when SQL Developer is trying to lookup options for autocomplete.  Any ideas what may be causing this?  I know how to turn off bind variables in procedures, but is there a way to turn them off for all new worksheets in SQL Developer?  I do not use them at all.

Comment: I just did a quick scan through all the tables in the schema, and don't see any that have special characters in them.  Just characters, numbers and the underscore.

Comment: Is jtemp_partial a view? Does it have bind variables in its code?

Comment: i've never seen that behavior before, that would be a bug. but your version is very many years old, can you upgrade to v4.1?

Comment: Are you executing the query in clear worksheet or there are some other queries?

Comment: jtemp_partial was just a temporary table created (of partial monthly charges) through a "create table as select..." query.  The query was executed in a clean worksheet with no bind variables in the query.  If the problem resurfaces (I did a clean install of the client including SQL developer on a new machine and I have not had the problem since) I will try downloading the newest version of it.

Comment: Sorry for the delay in answering, I just got notification of a reply to the question in my email today.